# How to request to Android for Activity Recognition permission using Expo?

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, expo

I would like to permit my application to use Activity Recognition and how is it possible? I've tried something like this.

In my `app.json`, I added below based on Expo [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#permissions)

```
      "permissions": [
        "com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION",
        "ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"
      ],
```

Then I am trying to make it appear by:

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION,
        {
          title: "testtitle",
          message:"testmessage",
          buttonNeutral: "testbtn1",
          buttonNegative: "testbtn2",
          buttonPositive: "testbtn3",
        }
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("success");
      } else {
        console.log("denied");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
```

Doing the above method doesn't work. How can I prompt it to the user? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: @roosi there is no error however I cannot allow my application to permit the user to allow ```ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION```. Whenever I am runnign the function, it does nothing.

Comment: Which API level is the app targeting? I think that permission was introduced in 29.